# Deleting Database Entry through url passing

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, parameter-passing

I have this simple code for showing the list of books from my database:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>
         Bookshelf
         </title>
    </head>
<body>
<table border='4' cellpadding='5'>

<th>Options</th>
<th>Book ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>ISBN</th>

<?php
foreach($books as $book)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="http://localhost/Bookstore/index.php/bookstore/showupdate"><input type="button" value="Update"/></a>
        <br>
        **<a href="http://localhost/Bookstore/index.php/bookstore/deleteentry?id=<?php echo $book->['book_id']; ?>"><input type="button" value="Delete"/></a>**
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_author'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_year'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_isbn'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>

</table>
</body>
</html
```

The bolded part would be my problem, It shows an error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in C:\www\Bookstore\application\views\showbooks.php on line 26

Could someone show me a much efficient/easier way to delete an entry using this technique where I just click links beside my database entry on views and it will delete? I have done this technique with simple PHP code and it works but this time I have to use frameworks, specifically codeigniter.

Answer (score 3):

`$book->['book_id'];` is bad syntax.

Use either `$book->book_id` for an object, or `$book['book_id']` for an array.

It appears that you're using an array, so the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the information, ill be sure to keep that in mind.